# How to get rid of the this grey block above bottom tab navigator in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I added this Tab Navigator with react native navigation and this grey block appears above it. How can I get rid of this?

[Current App Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaoin.png)

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipuV4.png)

Code:

```
        <Tab.Navigator  initialRouteName={'Home'} screenOptions={{ tabBarShowLabel: false, tabBarStyle: { borderTopWidth: 2, height: '20%', paddingTop: '5%', paddingBottom: '5%'}, headerShown: false, tabBarActiveBackgroundColor : 'white'}}  >
           <Tab.Screen name="..." component={...} options={{...}/>);}}}/>
           <Tab.Screen name="..." component={...} options={{...}/>);}}}/>
           <Tab.Screen name="..." component={...} options={{...}/>);}}}/>
           <Tab.Screen name="..." component={...} options={{...}/>);}}}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
```

Is this a problem with how I set up the Tab navigator?

Comment: @Rishivarsil., I hope you are using @react-navigation/native library. If it is, could you kindly provide the version of it?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `height: '20%',` and tested again? I think because of this style setting, the bottom bar is occupying the more space than required.

Comment: That "block" is your border (borderTopWidth: 2)

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel 
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-native": "^0.64.0",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10"

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel I removed the height style and it didn't change the grey block. It only changed the height of the white navbar.

Comment: @Abe It is hard to see in the screenshots I provided, but there is another grey bar in between the grey block and the white navbar which is the actual border. I confirmed this by changing the bordertopwidth to 10 and it did not increase the actual grey block.

Comment: @RishivarshilNelakurti., Is the issue exists for all tabs? Or it is for only one screen?  If it is for only one screen, there could be an issue with the screen styles. For ex, `<Tab.Screen name="..." component={...} options={{...}/>);}}}/>`. In this line check the component styles

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel In that component styles, I only inserted an icon no other styles.